# WebView2 in WinUI2 sometimes raised CoreProcessFailed error

Tags: uwp, webview2, winui

I'm trying to follow the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2) to use the WebView2 in WinUI 2, and sometimes I got the CoreProcessFailed error and sometimes the webview2 works fine.

Environment:
Win10 Enterprise 1909 with OS build:18363.1734

WebView2 runtime:92.0.902.84

I register WebView2's events as below:

```
 MyWebView.CoreWebView2Initialized += MyWebView_CoreWebView2Initialized;
 MyWebView.CoreProcessFailed += MyWebView_CoreProcessFailed;
 MyWebView.NavigationStarting += MyWebView_NavigationStarting;
 MyWebView.NavigationCompleted += MyWebView_NavigationCompleted;

 private void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("Navigation completed.");
 }

 private void MyWebView_NavigationStarting(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs args)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine("Navigation starting.");
 }

 private void MyWebView_CoreWebView2Initialized(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2InitializedEventArgs args)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("Initialized.");
 }

 private void MyWebView_CoreProcessFailed(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2ProcessFailedEventArgs args)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("Process failed.");
    Debug.WriteLine($"Reason:{args.Reason}, exit code:{args.ExitCode}, failed kind:{args.ProcessFailedKind}");
 }
```

And I try to navigate to a online page by clicking a button to change the WebView2's source.

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
        Uri targetUri = new Uri(addressBar.Text);
        MyWebView.Source = targetUri;
     }
     catch (FormatException ex)
     {
         // Incorrect address entered.
     }
 }
```

Then I sometimes got the output like below, and the WebView2's background is black.

Initialized.

Navigation starting.

Process failed. Reason:Unresponsive, exit code:259, failed kind:RenderProcessUnresponsive

Process failed. Reason:Unresponsive, exit code:259, failed kind:RenderProcessUnresponsive

Process failed. Reason:Unresponsive, exit code:259, failed kind:RenderProcessUnresponsive

[image: Here is the screenshot for your reference.]

What's I missing? What should I do?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The error `RenderProcessUnresponsive` means the main frame's render process is unresponsive. You could ask this in [WebView2Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues)

Comment: I also asked a question on [microsoft-ui-xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5816)

Comment: I'd suggest you ask this in the [WebView2 Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues) as well.

Comment: asked [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1711)

Comment: [WebView2 has been removed from 2.7.0-prerelease.210913003  due to some issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/releases/tag/v2.7.0-prerelease.210913003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with Microsoft expert, the root cause of the issue is the McAfee has blocked one of the msedgewebview2.exe process while try to initialize the WebView2. I already fixed this issue.